# Understand two or more keys with Hashmaps

Tags: java

I am having an issue with a hashmap. In my hashmap method i want to have two or more keywords as a key, oppose to having one. For example  I want the user to input some sentence containing two or more keywords assuming "professor name" is a keyword. For example

```
    String[] temp3 = { "instructor","teacher","mentor" };
    responses.put("professor name", temp3);
```

And the user enters "what is the professor name" the code just hangs. But on the other hand, if

```
  String[] temp3 = { "instructor","teacher","mentor" };
    responses.put("professor", temp3);
```

the code works. So I want to be able to enter some sentence containing two or more keywords oppose to one. I will appreciate any sort of assistance.

Here is my hashmap method

```
  private static HashMap<String, String[]> populateSynonymMap() {

    String[] temp1 = { "instructor","teacher","mentor" };
    responses.put("professor name", temp1);
    String[] temp2 = { "amount of test","test load","quantity of test" };

    return responses;
}
```

and here is my main method

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException, IOException {
    /* Initialization */
    HashMap<String, String[]> synonymMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    synonymMap = populateSynonymMap(); // populate the map


    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = null;
   /*End Initialization*/
    System.out.println("Welcome To DataBase ");
    System.out.println("What would you like to know?");

    System.out.print("> ");
    input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    String[] inputs = input.split(" ");
      for (String ing : inputs) { // iterate over each word of the sentence.
        boolean found = false;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : synonymMap.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String[] value = entry.getValue();
            if (key.equals(ing) || Arrays.asList(value).contains(ing)) {

                found = true;
                parseFile(entry.getKey());``
            }
          break;
     }
                if (found) {
            break;
        }


    }
}
```

Assuming that the ParseFile method works

Comment: Given a sentence key of "foo bar baz", using any single word should return the data, but what about multiple-word subsets, eg "foo baz" - should "foo baz" also find a match, or just single words of the sentence? Note: if you say "no" I will answer the question (because there's a simple solution), if "yes" maybe not :)

Comment: foo baz should also find a match

Comment: Is there a chance that the same word will be used in different keys? Eg "professor foo" and "professor bar" both share "professor" - if so, what data should be returned for "professor"? The last indexed data, the first, or a concatenation of both values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use String contains method to check multiple words. This will solve your problem of checking single word like 'professor' or multiple words like 'What is your professor name' problem.

```
    System.out.print("> ");
    input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : synonymMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String[] value = entry.getValue();
        if (input.contains(key) || key.contains(input)) {
            System.out.println("Input found in database -> " +Arrays.asList(value));
            break;
        }
    }
```

Now this will make it work with single word or multiple word. But this works when words are entered in same order. You can make it as elaborate as you like.

For example you may extend this to separate words of input and output from sentence from the sets and then find how many words matches etc.And I recommend that you use some different data structure which makes this task natural looking. You may think about having your database organized by words and synonyms relation so then you don't have to worry about cases where value from one synonym list has other synonym etc. And lookup can be just based on words.

Comment: Okay this code is fine, but what if the values of the hashmap also contains two or more words? eg if String[] temp1 = { "instructor name ","teacher room ","mentor place" };
    responses.put("professor name", temp1);

Comment: What other data structure do you recommend? @Kognizant

Comment: @ Curtis, sorry but did not understand your multiple word in value problem. We are not comparing it and even if we are comparing then as I said, you need to create three list of words one for input, one for keys and one for corresponding values. Then check if input is part of key list, if not then value list.

Comment: @Curtis, For datastructure, one needs to understand the full usecase, but  to take simplistic approach (more like database) I would for one id,word table and then model the synonym relationship between two words using relationship table. The other structure which naturally fits is graph, but, as I mentioned one need to get full use case.

Answer (score 0):

Use the type `HashMap<List<String>,String[]>` or `HashMap<Set<String>,String[]>` for the cases where the order does and does not matter respectively, in place of `HashMap<String,String[]>`.

In the first case, your keys are of type `List<String>`, and in the second case they are of type `Set<String>`.

Best practice would be to wrap all keys with Collections.unmodifiable* methods before using them as keys - if they are modified while in HashMap entires, the behavior of your program will be undefined.

Comment: Ah, backticker thingers.  Was wondering how to get those insets.  TYVM.

Comment: This answer leaves out an important issue: what should the program check for when doing the map lookup?  In the `Set<String>` case, if a sentence has n words, the program will need to create 2**n-1 sets to do the lookup--at which point it might be worth asking whether a totally different data structure might be better.  This is _not_ an easy problem.

Comment: @ajb - You're not wrong!  But the question specifically asks how to use compound keys in a HashMap, not what the most efficient or performant way to do a full text keyword search is.

Comment: Right, but I think he also wants to know how to use the map once he's set it up.  (The efficiency angle was an extra bonus thought I threw in free of charge.)